# Passing data between different URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I need to check where did the incoming request came from before loading a page

ex:

```
for user to view www.mysite/page1.aspx

request should come through www.othersite/page1.aspx
```

so on page1 load in mysite i need to check whether the request came from page1 in othersite.

i have tried Page.Request.UrlReferrer but i saw there some posts which tells every browser might not support Page.Request.UrlReferrer.

i can not pass visible parameters on URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when you do not want to allow request from arbitrary sites.

What you can do is, create a variable in session and put this variable in the Page1.aspx. When the page posts back, you should get that variable back and it should also match the one stored in the session. If it does not, you can be sure that the request is from some other server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PostBackUrl` on the start page

And access your parameters with `PreviousPage` in the arrived page

```
if (this.PreviousPage != null)
{
    var control = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("..."); //Adjust your Id and add cast
}
```

Nota : This was also created to provide greater security redirection setting.